# C++ win32 API Message box button clicked

Tags: c++, winapi, api, messagebox

I have just started learning how to program Windows GUI's using the low level Win32 API and C++ so please bear with me.

I have a message box which is displayed at one point and as you can see below it is set to an OK/Cancel box

```
    MessageBox(hWnd, L"Hello", L"Caption", MB_OKCANCEL);
```

My question is, how do you check which of the two (or possibly more) buttons were pressed and act accordingly?

Thank you

Tom

Comment: Straight from MSDN documentation on MessageBox : "If the function succeeds, the return value is one of the following menu-item values." followed by your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the [MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) description. The return type is the value of the button clicked. For example, `IDOK` when the user pressed the "OK" button.

Answer (score 6):

you can use

```
int msgboxID=MessageBox(NULL, "DOCTOR WHO","BBC", MB_OKCANCEL | MB_DEFBUTTON2);
switch(msgboxID){
    case IDCANCEL:// you check msdn for more cases
     {
     PostQuitMessage(0);
     return 0;
     }


               }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

MessageBox() call returns an integer value providing the value of button clicked.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, a Google search for `MessageBox` yields a [link to Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Have a look at the "Return Value" section.
Does this help?